# Many to One Relationship returns NULL List of Child Object

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have 2 classes. USER class & ORDER class.
Order class has User object with @ManyToOne relationship.
When the RestController retrieves the Order object post insertion of Order object using @PostMapping,it returns null value for nested User object

### Rest Controller

```
@RestController
public class OrderController {

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

@Transactional
@PostMapping(value = "api/v1/create/order")
public Order createOrder(@RequestBody Order order){

    entityManager.persist(order);
    return order;

}
```

}

### Order class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "booking_order")
public class Order {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
Integer orderID;
@Column
String transactionAmount;
@Column
@CreationTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
Date bookingTimestamp;
@ManyToOne
User user;


public Order(){}

public Integer getOrderID() {
    return orderID;
}

public void setOrderID(Integer orderID) {
    this.orderID = orderID;
}

public String getTransactionAmount() {
    return transactionAmount;
}

public void setTransactionAmount(String transactionAmount) {
    this.transactionAmount = transactionAmount;
}

public Date getBookingTimestamp() {
    return bookingTimestamp;
}

public void setBookingTimestamp(Date bookingTimestamp) {
    this.bookingTimestamp = bookingTimestamp;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
}
```

### User Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
Integer id;
@Column(unique = true)
String username;
@Column
String password;


public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

}
```

### Input JSON

{
    "transactionAmount" : "100.50",
    "user":{
        "id":1
    }
}

### Order Response

{
    "orderID": 1,
    "transactionAmount": "100.50",
    "bookingTimestamp": "2019-05-15T20:44:43.234+0000",
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": null,
        "password": null
    }
}

Comment: while you create order from controller, are you setting values for user properly?

Comment: I have already created user with user_id : 1

Comment: In that case, in your controller you need to get user with id=1 and set it as user of new order that you are creating.

Comment: I am just adding a reference of user i.e user_id : 1, and it should return the complete user object..ideally...which is not happening..And since it's a foreign key,it must work

Comment: did you try - @JoinColumn(name="user_id")  in you order class?

Comment: I tried it too...But same result